# FSharp.Data.SqlProvider and FSharp.Core version mismatch VS2017

Tags: f#, .net-core

I have an F# project in VS 2017 using FSharp.Data.SqlProvider 1.1.11 and FSharp.Core 4.4.1.0. I have an .fsx file that does what I want. I copied its contents to an .fs file. I’m trying to call that .fs file from an MSTest class. It’s throwing an exception saying it can’t load FSharp.Core version 4.3.1.0.

Comment: What .net version is your project targeting in your project settings? Check out: https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#fsharpcore-version-numbers

Comment: Both the F# class library and MSTest project target 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the test project I added FSharp.Core 4.3.1 and a binding redirect pointing versions 0.0.0 to 4.4.1 to 4.3.1. All is well.